# Parameter Enums in C#

Tags: c#, enums

I'm used to programming in Java however for this project I'm supposed to be using C#, I'm trying to convert my Packet system over from my Java project, however I'm running into some issues using the C# Compiler. Here's the code.

```
abstract class Packet
{
    public static enum PacketTypes
    {
        INVALID(-1), LOGIN(00);

        private int packetId;

        private PacketTypes(int packetId)
        {
            this.packetId = packetId;
        }

        public int getId()  { return packetId; }

    }
}
```

This is actually exactly how it's done in my Java Code, and I have the individual packets extend the Packet class. I'm trying to figure out how to make this all come together in C#. Perhaps having a separate class for each packet isn't the way it should be done here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike Java where `enum`s are classes, in C# `enum`s are plain values. They cannot have member functions or fields.

One approach that could help is to define an extension method for your `enum`, like this:

```
public static class PacketTypesExtensions {
    static readonly IDictionary<PacketTypes,int> IdForType = new Dictionary<PacketTypes,int> {
        { PacketTypes.INVALID, -1 }
    ,   { PacketTypes.LOGIN,    0 }
    };
    static readonly IDictionary<PacketTypes,string> DescrForType = new Dictionary<PacketTypes,string> {
        { PacketTypes.INVALID, "<invalid packet type>" }
    ,   { PacketTypes.LOGIN,   "<user login>" }
    };
    public static string Description(this PacketTypes t) {
        return DescrForType[t];
    }
    public static int Id(this PacketTypes t) {
        return IdForType[t];
    }
}
```

This lets you keep Java syntax:

```
PacketTypes pt = ... // <<== Assign a packet type here
int id = pt.Id();    // This calls the static extension method
string d = pt.Description();
```

Comment: This.. is.. beautiful. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve, but you can set values for particular `enum` elements in C#:

```
public enum PacketTypes
{
    INVALID = -1;
    LOGIN = 0;
}
```

Because `enum` is by default backed by `int`, you can cast it from/to `int` without additional code.

`enum`s in C# cannot content any members, so you can't add methods/properties/fields to `enum` declaration.

Comment: Can you set the enum using an int? perhaps like

`Private PacketTypes PacketType;

PacketType = 0;`

Comment: Yes, you can, but you have to perform explicit cast: `PacketType = (PacketTypes)0;`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this in addition to Marcins answer.

```
public enum PacketTypes
{
    INVALID = -1;
    LOGIN = 0;
}

public class Packet
{
    public PacketTypes PacketType { get; set;}
}
```

In your code somewhere, you would do this

```
public void DoSomething()
{
    var packet = new Packet();
    packet.PacketType = PacketTypes.INVALID; // Assign packtype
    Console.WriteLine(packet.PacketType.ToString()); // Retrieve and print 
}
```